# How do I get predictions on new data using a fitted statsmodel GLMgam model?

Tags: python, statsmodels

After running the code form the example found in the documentation of the GLMgam class of the statsmodel package,

```
from statsmodels.gam.api import GLMGam, BSplines
from statsmodels.gam.tests.test_penalized import df_autos
df_autos_train = df_autos.iloc[0:165]
df_autos_test = df_autos.iloc[165:205]
x_spline = df_autos_train[['weight', 'hp']]
bs = BSplines(x_spline, df=[12, 10], degree=[3, 3])
alpha = np.array([21833888.8, 6460.38479])
gam_bs = GLMGam.from_formula('city_mpg ~ fuel + drive', data=df_autos_train, smoother=bs, alpha=alpha)
res_bs = gam_bs.fit()
print(res_bs.summary())
```

I fail to get the prediction

```
res_bs.predict(exog = df_autos_test[['fuel', 'drive']], exog_smooth = df_autos_test[['weight', 'hp']])
```

gives me the error

```
File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 116, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), 0)' is an invalid key
```

Comment: possibly a bug in pandas support. `exog_smooth = np.asarray(df_autos_test[['weight', 'hp']])` works for me. And thanks for an example that can be immediately run.

Comment: Nice thank you! I feel a bit silly, I was sure I had tried that (using .values). Well problem solved thank you so much again!